# PHP Built-in Web server not found locally

Tags: php

I'm trying to run a local server with PHP. the command `php -S 0.0.0.0:9999` used to work on another computer when accessing the server using its IP address but not on this computer.

I don't know if Apache is not forwarding the port correctly.

There are no errors on the PHP CLI interface, I just can't access from another computer.

Comment: Maybe this computer is running a firewall (as it should)? Do remember the built in server is only for local development only, it should never be used for production / exposed services.

Comment: How should I forward it? I'm on Fedora (last one was Debian) and supposedly this command would suffice: `firewall-cmd --add-service=http --add-service=https --permanent` but it only shows the main web page for the Apache server and nothing else.

Comment: Apache shouldn't even be in this mix. Does he try to access `http://yourip:9999` ?

Comment: When I go to that site it shows that it couldn't be reached (on the remote computer)

Comment: @JimL what could it be if it's not Apache?